# is the `synonym` in a `typedef` mandatory?

Tags: c++, syntax, typedef

I encountered this in a code review:

```
typedef struct C { int i; };
```

It compiles.

Apart from it being C-style, where structs are in a separate 'namespace', and need to be typedeffed in order to use later on, I found it weird that there is nothing defined with this typedef...

So: doesn't `typedef` require a type argument and an alias argument?

Comment: In C, structs do not 'need to be typedeffed' in order to be used.

Comment: @William: indeed, but then you need to prepend them with `struct`, or am I mistaken?  ( `struct A{}; struct A a;` while C++ allows `struct A{}; A a;` )

Comment: You are not mistaken.  There seems to be a common misconception that the typedef is actually required for the struct to be used at all, rather than merely a preference to avoid using the word 'struct' at each variable declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `typedef` requires another argument. That `typedef` won't do anything.

Anyway it's not an error, just a deprecate usage of `typedef`.

---

C standard (n1256 in 6.7.7) talks about `typedef`. It doesn't say this usage is deprecated, but compilers report it is, since such statement has no effect.

Comment: Thanks; have you got any reference to it's deprecation?

Answer (score 5):

A quick glance over n3225 doesn't show any requirement that a name is required to be present. The text that comes the most near just says

> In a simple-declaration, the optional init-declarator-list can be omitted only when declaring a class (clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the decl-specifier-seq contains either a class-specifier, an elaborated- type-specifier with a class-key (9.1), or an enum-specifier.

So your code seems to be valid, but I think it smells bad.

Comment: FYI, the quote is from `7/3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Thank you for testing your code with Comeau C/C++!
Tell others about http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout !

Your Comeau C/C++ test results are as follows:


Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 1: warning: declaration requires a typedef name
  typedef struct C { int i; };
                             ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely using very old compiler, which allows you to compile that line. Using g++ 4.3.0 (which is already fairly old), without any additional options, give this :

```
g++ dfg.cpp
dfg.cpp:2: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration
```

So, try to compile that using a compiler which is more c++ standard compliant.

Comment: VS2005.  Codepad.org, which uses g++ 4.1.2.  Still: it's just a warning on more recent compilers.

Comment: @xtofl Treat warnings as errors, and your code will greatly improve.

Comment: @xtofl:  I'm kind of chuckling at your notion of "just a warning".  Ideally, you want production code compiling with no errors and no warnings at the highest error level (which usually treats warnings as errors).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that's not valid. You're using the keyword `typedef` to create an alias, then not specifying what the alias should be!

(Strictly speaking it's deprecated, not invalid. But hey.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the parallels between:

```
typedef struct C { int i; };
extern  struct P { int i; };
```

GCC 4.2.1 with no explicit warnings enabled (`gcc -c xxx.c`) says of the first:

```
xxx.c:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
xxx.c:2: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

Note that they are only warnings; they are not an error because the standard allows the notation, though it does not do very much.  In each case, the example simply declares a structure type, which can be used by the name `struct C` or `struct P`.  The storage classes are irrelevant because no object is named.  In C++, those declarations also declare types `C` and `P` (but that would also happen if the `typedef` or extern`was not there); in C, those types (`C`and`P`) are not declared.

In the C standard, `typedef` is treated as a storage class, like `extern` and `static` are storage classes.  That means that the following code is legitimate:

```
typedef struct C { int i; } name1;
extern  struct P { int i; } name2;
```

It declares the same two structure types as before, but now the `typedef` declares an alias for `struct C` which is `name1`, and the `extern` line states that another translation unit (TU) defines a variable called `name2` of the type `struct P`.  Neither is vacuous (except that the definitions are not used later in the 2-line TU shown).

The C standard allows many weird things.  For example:

```
int unsigned typedef u;
```

It's a perfectly valid - but totally abnormal - way of writing:

```
typedef unsigned int u;
```

There is a section in C99 §6.11.5 (under Future Language Directions) which says:

> 6.11.5 Storage-class specifiers
>
> The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

That makes my weird example in violation of §6.11.5.

#### Summary

- The code reviewed is syntactically correct in C, both C89 and C99.
- It is also, AFAIK, syntactically valid in C++ - but it is even more pointless there than in C since `struct C { int i; };` with no typedef introduces the type C (as well as `struct C`).
- The code reviewed should not be accepted - it is reasonable to require it to be fixed.

The correct fix might be to remove the storage class (`typedef`), or it might be to introduce a name as an alias for `struct C`.  Since the code compiles without the alias, it is more likely correct to remove the storage class.